# I have store the image file in admin through post method but when trying to put the same code for pdf/word its not working

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to upload pdf file on page but its not working as done with image and its working

I have made a column filepath for pdf/word then code in postcontroller but not working

public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
    $this->validate($request, [


       'title' =>'required',
        'featured'=>'required|image',
        'content'=>'required',
        'category_id'=>'required'

    ]);

    $featured= $request->featured;
    $featured_new_name=time().$featured->getClientOriginalName();
    $featured->move('uploads/posts', $featured_new_name);

    $post = Post::create([

        'title'=>$request->title,
        'content'=>$request->content,
        'featured'=>'uploads/posts/'. $featured_new_name,
        'category_id'=>$request->category_id,
        'slug'=>str_slug($request->title)
```

and when I trying to add "filepath column name in data base" for pdf/ word then using in public function store(Request $request)
    {

```
    $this->validate($request, [


       'title' =>'required',
        'featured'=>'required|image',
        'content'=>'required',
        'category_id'=>'required',

        'file' => 'required',

    ]);

    $featured= $request->featured;
    $featured_new_name=time().$featured->getClientOriginalName();
    $featured->move('uploads/posts', $featured_new_name);

    $file=$request->file;
    $file=time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $filename = rand(11111111, 99999999). '.' . $extension;
    $fullPath = $filename;
    $request->file('file')->move(base_path() . '/uploads/pdf/', $filename);



    $post = Post::create([

        'title'=>$request->title,
        'content'=>$request->content,
        'featured'=>'uploads/posts/'. $featured_new_name,
        'file'=>'uploads/pdf' .$filename,

        'category_id'=>$request->category_id,
        'slug'=>str_slug($request->title)


    ]);


  Session::flash('success', 'New Blog has been Published on Website for Particular Menu');

  return redirect()->back();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue in your code, you are saving the image in your base path whereas you want to save it into your public path so use

```
$request->file('file')->move(public_path() . '/uploads/pdf/', $filename);
```

instead of

```
  $request->file('file')->move(base_path() . '/uploads/pdf/', $filename);
```

To save file update your code 
validation of file type

`'file'    => 'required|mimes:pdf,doc|max:10000',`

save file

```
  if($request->hasfile('file'))
    {
        $file = $request->file;
        $input = rand(11111111, 99999999).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/pdf/100');
        $file->move($destinationPath, $input);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code.. and in this i can upload the image , but for pdf or words how can i do that

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [


           'title' =>'required',
            'content'=>'required',
            'category_id'=>'required',
            'featured'=>'required|image',


        ]);

Comment: $featured= $request->featured;
                $featured_new_name=time().$featured->getClientOriginalName();

                $featured->move('uploads/posts', $featured_new_name);

Comment: $post = Post::create([

            'title'=>$request->title,
            'content'=>$request->content,
            'featured'=>'uploads/posts/'. $featured_new_name,
            'category_id'=>$request->category_id,
            'slug'=>str_slug($request->title)


        ]);

Comment: Check i have updated the code for pdf file. @user10927970